# What does this loading bar mean in GIF export in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, gif

It's been loading for 5 minutes at the same mark, but it's not even clear to me what it's loading, I haven't exported anything yet.

[image]

And I get this error if I try to click on Save As.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately tech support is generally off-topic here. You should really contact Adobe. Anything I could suggest would be a guess. The save for web dialog is generally designed for web page sized images. Anything that is too big (in pixels) can cause it to crash.

Comment: What Billy Kerr said, and plus you have 400+ frames of animation of a 900x500 document: probably PS run out of memory or could be a PS limitation: normally you'd want to use a video for such large animation

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - I didn't notice the number of frames. That's almost certainly the problem.